# No SupportFragmentManager

Tags: android, kotlin, robolectric, fragmentmanager, appcompatactivity

For a unit test I have to add a SupportFragment to a Activity. I build a AppCompatActivity with Robolectric like this

```
mActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(AppCompatActivity::class.java)
            .create()
            .start()
            .resume()
            .get()
```

Now I want to call `mActivity.supportFragmentManager()` but there is not Method for this call. Only the deprecated `fragmentManager` What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is mActivity declared as AppCompatActivity?

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. mActivity  was declared as Activity and not as AppCompatActivity. Thank you!